# Loop and auto submit HTML form within PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I am trying to send a couple of variables via HTML form to another PHP page, 
I am no expert in PHP but know enough to get me by most days, 
and have had this working with no issues in other situations,

But alas PHP is just not my thing so I am here to ask the Gurus of the coding world for a pearl of wisdom,

Ok so let me break it down for you,

I have a PHP IPN (PayPal) page that is executed when a customer makes a purchase, the original code just checks for successful sale and then sends out some email to myself and the user accordingly,

I also have a licensing script that auto-generates a license,

I use a HTML form within the page so that when the sale is marked as successful a license is generated and sent to the user at the same time the emails are sent,

All pretty basic stuff, and have had this working in 3 other scripts with no problems, but for some reason i just cant get my head around it this time, and cant seem to get this to work,

I contacted the author of my store script to make sure i was using the correct variables in the form, he said that the variables needed are :

```
$usr->username

$usr->email

$crow->title
```

Here is the IPN page :

```
<?php
  define("_VALID_PHP", true);
  define("_PIPN", true);

  ini_set('log_errors', true);
  ini_set('error_log', dirname(__file__) . '/ipn_errors.log');
  if (isset($_POST['payment_status'])) {
      require_once ("../../init.php");

      include (BASEPATH . 'lib/class_pp.php');
      $demo = getValue("demo", Content::gTable, "name = 'paypal'");

      $listener = new IpnListener();
      $listener->use_live = $demo;
      $listener->use_ssl = false;
      $listener->use_curl = true;

      try {
          $listener->requirePostMethod();
          $ppver = $listener->processIpn();
      }
      catch (exception $e) {
          error_log($e->getMessage());
          exit(0);
      }

      $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
      $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
      $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
      $payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
      $mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
      $mc_fee = isset($_POST['mc_fee']) ? floatval($_POST['mc_fee']) : 0.00;

      list($user_id, $sesid) = explode('_', $_POST['custom']);
      $mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
      $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];

      $getxn_id = $core->verifyTxnId($txn_id);

      $cartrow = $content->getCartContent($sesid);
      $totalrow = Content::getCart($sesid);
      $v1 = compareFloatNumbers($mc_gross, $totalrow->totalprice, "=");
      $items = array();

      $pp_email = getValue("extra", Content::gTable, "name = 'paypal'");

      if ($ppver) {
          if ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed') {
              if ($receiver_email == $pp_email && $v1 == true && $getxn_id == true) {
                  if ($cartrow) {
                      foreach ($cartrow as $crow) {
                          $data = array(
                              'txn_id' => sanitize($txn_id),
                              'pid' => $crow->pid,
                              'uid' => intval($user_id),
                              'downloads' => 0,
                              'file_date' => time(),
                              'ip' => sanitize($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
                              'created' => "NOW()",
                              'payer_email' => sanitize($payer_email),
                              'payer_status' => sanitize($payer_status),
                              'item_qty' => $crow->total,
                              'price' => $crow->total * $crow->price,
                              'coupon' => $totalrow->coupon,
                              'tax' => $totalrow->totaltax,
                              'mc_fee' => $mc_fee,
                              'currency' => sanitize($mc_currency),
                              'pp' => "PayPal",
                              'status' => 1,
                              'active' => 1);

                          $items[$crow->price] = $crow->title;   
                          $db->insert(Products::tTable, $data);
                      }

                      unset($crow);
                      $xdata = array(
                        'invid' => date('Ymd').$db->insertid(),
                        'user_id' => intval($user_id),
                        'items' => serialize($items),
                        'coupon' => $totalrow->coupon,
                        'originalprice' => $totalrow->originalprice,
                        'tax' => $totalrow->tax,
                        'totaltax' => $totalrow->totaltax,
                        'total' => $totalrow->total,
                        'totalprice' => $totalrow->totalprice,
                        'currency' => sanitize($_POST['currency_code']),
                        'created' => "NOW()",
                      );
                    $db->insert(Content::inTable, $xdata);                  }

                  /* == Notify Administrator == */

                  require_once (BASEPATH . "lib/class_mailer.php");
                  $row2 = Core::getRowById(Content::eTable, 5);
                  $usr = Core::getRowById(Users::uTable, $user_id);

                  $body = str_replace(array(
                      '[USERNAME]',
                      '[STATUS]',
                      '[PRODUCT]',
                      '[TOTAL]',
                      '[PP]',
                      '[IP]'), array(
                      $usr->username,
                      "Completed",
                      $crow->title,
                      $totalrow->totalprice,
                      "PayPal",
                      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), $row2->body);

                  $newbody = cleanOut($body);

                  $mailer = Mailer::sendMail();
                  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                            ->setSubject($row2->subject)
                            ->setTo(array($core->site_email => $core->site_name))
                            ->setFrom(array($core->site_email => $core->site_name))
                            ->setBody($newbody, 'text/html');

                  $mailer->send($message);

                  /* == Notify User == */
                  $row3 = Core::getRowById(Content::eTable, 8);
                  $val = '
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2">';
                    $val .= '
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="20"><strong>#</strong></td>
                        <td class="header">' . Lang::$word->PRD_NAME . '</td>
                        <td class="header">' . Lang::$word->PRD_PRICE . '</td>
                        <td class="header">' . Lang::$word->TXN_QTY . '</td>
                        <td class="header">' . Lang::$word->CKO_TPRICE . '</td>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    ';
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($cartrow as $ccrow) {
                    $i++;
                    $val .= '
                    <tr>
                      <td style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed">' . $i . '.</td>
                      <td style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed">' . sanitize($ccrow->title, 30, false) . 

'</td>
                      <td style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed">' . $core->formatMoney($ccrow->price) . 

'</td>
                      <td align="center" style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed">' . $ccrow->total . '</td>
                      <td align="right" style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed">' . $core->formatMoney($ccrow-

>total * $ccrow->price) . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                    }
                    unset($ccrow);
                    $val .= '
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="4" align="right" valign="top" style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-

style:dashed"><strong>';
                        $val .= Lang::$word->CKO_SUBT . ':<br />';
                        $val .= Lang::$word->CKO_DISC . ':<br />';
                        $val .= Lang::$word->VAT . ':<br />
                        </strong></td>
                      <td align="right" valign="top" style="border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#bbb; border-bottom-style:dashed"><strong>';
                        $val .= $core->formatMoney($totalrow->originalprice) . '<br />';
                        $val .= '- ' . $core->formatMoney($totalrow->coupon) . '<br />';
                        $val .= '+ ' . $core->formatMoney($totalrow->total * $totalrow->tax) . '<br />
                        </strong>';
                        $val .= ' </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="4" align="right" valign="top"><strong style="color:#F00">' . Lang::$word->CKO_GTOTAL . ':</strong></td>
                      <td align="right" valign="top"><strong style="color:#F00">' . $core->formatMoney($totalrow->tax * $totalrow->total + $totalrow->total) 

. '</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>';

                  $body3 = str_replace(array(
                      '[USERNAME]',
                      '[ITEMS]',
                      '[SITE_NAME]',
                      '[URL]'), array(
                      $usr->username,
                      $val,
                      $core->site_name,
                      SITEURL), $row3->body);

                  $newbody2 = cleanOut($body3);

                  $mailer2 = Mailer::sendMail();
                  $message2 = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                            ->setSubject($row3->subject)
                            ->setTo(array($usr->email => $usr->username))
                            ->setFrom(array($core->site_email => $core->site_name))
                            ->setBody($newbody2, 'text/html');

                  $mailer2->send($message2);

                  $db->delete(Content::crTable, "user_id='" . $sesid . "'");
                  $db->delete(Content::exTable, "user_id='" . $sesid . "'");
                  $db->delete(Products::rTable, "user_id='" . $sesid . "'");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('Form'))">
<form id='Form' name='form' action='http://www.****************.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo $_POST['usr->username'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='email' value='<?php echo $_POST['usr->email'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='original_url' value='http://www.****************ipn.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='projname' value='<?php echo $_POST['crow->title'];?>'>
<input type=hidden name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
                  $sale_amount = '$totalrow->totalprice';
                  $product = '$crow->title';
                  include('/home/**********************************.php');
              }

          } else {
              /* == Failed Transaction= = */
              require_once (BASEPATH . "lib/class_mailer.php");
              $row = Core::getRowById(Content::eTable, 6);
              $usr = Core::getRowById(Users::uTable, $user_id);


              $body = str_replace(array('[USERNAME]','[STATUS]','[TOTAL]','[PP]','[IP]'), array(
              $usr->username,"Failed",$core->formatMoney($gross),"PayPal",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), $row->body);

              $newbody = cleanOut($body);

              $mailer = Mailer::sendMail();
              $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
              ->setSubject($row->subject)
              ->setTo(array($core->site_email => $core->site_name))
              ->setFrom(array($core->site_email => $core->site_name))
              ->setBody($newbody, 'text/html');

              $mailer->send($message);

          }
      }
  }
?>
```

and here is the FORM code im using :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('Form'))">
<form id='Form' name='form' action='http://www.****************.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo $_POST['usr->username'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='email' value='<?php echo $_POST['usr->email'];?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='original_url' value='http://www.****************ipn.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='projname' value='<?php echo $_POST['crow->title'];?>'>
<input type=hidden name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also aware that I may need to use a foreach() loop but ill cross that bridge when i get there, I really need to figure this out first.

So there we are, i think i have left enough info, details and code, 
If i have missed anything out that might help just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['usr->username'];?>">
```

you are calling a POST variable 'usr->username' which does not exist, as far as I see in your script. Instead, use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $usr->username;?>">
```

That would set the value of the input to the property 'username' of the 'usr' object you define on the line:

```
$usr = Core::getRowById(Users::uTable, $user_id);
```

The same applies to the other fields.

Hope it helps :)

Regards

Comment: Thanks e.lopez, i thought it would be something stupid simple lol, ill make the edit and see what happens :)